# Setting autologon to a local user after joining to a domain

Tags: powershell, sysinternals

I'm building an application to assist in re-configuring devices on our network. I've got the entire script working except for setting the device to auto logon. Nothing I am trying seems to work. Now, the use is a little different, as the device will be joined to the domain, but logged on with a local user account. I'm trying to use the Sysinternals Autologon utility, but it is not working.
Here is the relevant code for logging on:

```
function  Set-Autologon {

    
    param (
        [Parameter()][string]$domain
    )

    $exePath = "$scriptPath\$autologon"
    $user = 'aloha'
    $logonPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
    $defaultdomain = "DefaultDomainName"
    $alohass = '<very long string>' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
    $alohaptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($alohass)
    $aloharesult = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($alohaptr)

    LogInfo "Setting auto logon for $aloha user."
    Start-Process -FilePath $exePath -ArgumentList "/accepteula", $user, $domain, $aloharesult -Wait -Verbose
}
```

The domain is being passed in as that is coming from a CSV file. The `$key` is set somewhere else in the script. I've tried with the `/accepteula` in both the front and the back.
What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, we have no idea what is in `$scriptPath`, nor what is inside `$autologon` if anything at all. You should not create a path like `"$scriptPath\$autologon"` anyway, but use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet for that.

Comment: `$autologon` is just the name of the executable, Autologon.exe. `$scriptPath` is just that, that path that the script is running from. It is where autologon.exe is being housed as well.

Comment: But.. does the function also know that? Are these vars script scoped? Please elaborate on _but it is not working_

Comment: Even if I take all of the code out of the function and run it by itself, and hardcode all of the values, nothing is happening. Autologon looks like it is running, but the logon does not get set. I have tried to run Autologon from the GUI, and even that is coming back with an error "The username or password is incorrect".

Comment: So, does the autologon app need a plain-text password or a SecureString?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with "/accepteula" as the last argument but, you can create a DWORD registry key in HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\AutoLogon for EulaAccept=1 before running the exe. You could also try starting the autologon.exe with the /accepteula flag and then immediately killing the process before running with the username/credentials arguments.